# Stuck on MIT APP Inventor:

Tags: android

Once I have completed the form, I cannot see the the form's output in the ResultsLabel I created. Attached is a screenshot below, does it look OK?

All help appreciated![image]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your statement "I cannot see the form's output in the label", is it possible that it's hidden behind the keyboard?  Press the 'Done' button to hide the keyboard when you're done typing.

Regarding your question "does it look OK":

- Your first StoreValue event is saving the value as the tag, which probably isn't great practice but can work
- However, your second StoreValue overwrites the first one, and the third StoreValue overwrites the second one because you're using the same tag for all three.

If you want to save the two thumbpositions for that particular name you should do this:

```
TinyDB.StoreValue 
       tag   = {name.text}
       value = {make a list
                    {cashrequired.thumbposition}
                    {period.thumbposition}
```